# How to Change Author Posts URL

Tags: url-rewriting, archives, author

How can I display an authors archive by author id instead author slug like

```
http://example.com/author/author_slug/
```

to

```
http://example.com/author/123/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after investigation into wp rewrite rules for author and with help of @Mark Davidson everything is now working perfect author archives pagination and feed rss atom etc.

below is the code which i have created and pasted here to help others, Thanks Mark Davidson for providing a pattern.

```
// add our custom rewrite rules for author archives
add_action('author_rewrite_rules', 'my_author_rewrite_rules');

function my_author_rewrite_rules() {
    $author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]';
    $author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
    $author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
    $author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
    return $author_rules;
}
```

this function will totally replace the author rewrite rules, if anyone want to add new rules and don't want to replace existing then he/she need to supply $author_rules argument in function like.

```
function my_author_rewrite_rules($author_rules) {
   // new rules here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the following rewrite rule ( you'll want to add this in your `functions.php`

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'author/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?author=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Be aware that you might need to flush your rules for it to become active. You can do this with [rewrite plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite).

Comment: is this work with pagination?

Comment: and can i wrap this in a function and hook it in author_rewrite_rules like this `// add our custom rewrite rules for user data
 add_action('author_rewrite_rules', 'my_author_rewrite_rules');
 
 function my_author_rewrite_rules($author_rules) {
  $author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]';
  return $author_rules;
 }`

Comment: with your rewrite rule pagination is not working, giving me 404 error when i am navigating to /page/2/ or so on.