# How to create custom authors links

Tags: urls, author

I would like to create custom authors links that lead to the page specified by the author. Instead of `http://example.com/author/example` for example `http://facebook.com/authorexample`.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate, this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110312/how-to-change-author-posts-url) hope will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @Anjum is not a duplicate. Answer you linked is about **author archive** in wordpress. This question is about **author url**, the one that is filled in profile page in backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `author_link` filter to change the author's link

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpse110967_author_link', 10,2 ); 
function wpse110967_author_link( $link, $user_id ){

  //Retrieve authors url from user meta
  $_link = esc_url( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wpse110967_author_link', true ) );

  if( $_link )
      $link = $_link;

  return $link;
}
```

In the above example its assumed that you've stored the author-specified url as user meta with the key `wpse110967_author_link`. If no url is found, it fallback to the default WordPress url.