# Can change twentytwelve_entry_meta "by-author" links?

Tags: author, links

In the Twenty twelve theme, the `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function shows "by-author" links (i.e., the ones that have the title "View all posts by xxxx") by using `user_nicename`.  So when a "difficult" admin username is chosen, that link can look something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/author/site_admin_45471/">John Smith</a>
```

Is there any way to change that `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function, and keep the link to the author's other posts, but use something other than the "user_nicename" in the body of the link?  E.g.:

```
<a href="http://example.com/author/author_id/">John Smith</a>
```

**update**:

My (slightly altered from default) `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function:

```
function twentytwelve_entry_meta() {
// Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' ) );

// Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
$tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'twentytwelve' ) );

$date = sprintf( '<time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>',
esc_url( get_permalink() ),
esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
esc_html( get_the_date() )
);

$author = sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ) ),
get_the_author()
);

// Translators: 1 is category, 2 is tag, 3 is the date and 4 is the author's name.
if ( $tag_list ) {
$utility_text = __( 'Posted on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>', 'twentytwelve' );
} elseif ( $categories_list ) {
$utility_text = __( 'Posted on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>', 'twentytwelve' );
} else {
$utility_text = __( 'Posted on %3$s<span class="by-author"> by %4$s</span>', 'twentytwelve' );
}

printf(
$utility_text,
$categories_list,
$tag_list,
$date,
$author
);
}
```

The rewrite function from the apparently duplicated question:

```
// add our custom rewrite rules for author archives
add_action('author_rewrite_rules', 'my_author_rewrite_rules');

function my_author_rewrite_rules() {
$author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]';
$author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
$author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
$author_rules['author/([0-9]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
return $author_rules;
}
```

After this I re-saved permalinks.  Following this, the author URL hasn't changed; furthermore, clicking the URL now returns a 404.  Not sure if I have to further modify the `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function after adding the `my_author_rewrite_rules()` function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change Author Posts URL](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110312/how-to-change-author-posts-url)

Comment: First, [that function can be overwritten](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php#L362) simply by creating a function of your own of the same name in a child theme, which is the proper way to modify the theme. 

Second, it looks to me like the URL for that link is generated here: `get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )`. So, what you are really asking is "Can I alter the author posts link?".

Comment: I am rewriting that function with a replacement in my child theme's `functions.php` - it's just that I don't know how to accomplish that particular aspect of it.

Comment: See the post marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I placed that function in my child theme's `functions.php` but nothing appears to have changed.  I'm missing something.

Comment: Reset your permalinks-- go to the "Permalinks" admin page and save settings.

Comment: I did that, but no change, except the old link returns a 404.  I get the feeling that placing the function isn't all I have to do?

Comment: If the "duplicate" does not solve your problem then edit this question to include everything you've tried including _all_ relevant code.

Comment: Maybe following the insertion of the second function I need to change `( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) )` but I don't know what to (even if this is right).

Answer (score 1):

Well for anyone who may be interested, I worked out that the answer, after adding the `my_author_rewrite_rules` function as above (thank you), is to edit the `twentytwelve_entry_meta()` function by replacing this:

```
esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
```

with this:

```
esc_url( sprintf( __( home_url().'/author/%d', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author_meta('ID') ) ),
```

It also means similarly changing the code underneath the `archive-header` class in the `author.php` file.

Comment: I guess that could be `site_url()` in certain configurations.